# need to extract zip files having spaces in filename

Tags: windows

i need to use windows command prompt to unzip files. I have files with spaces in the file name which is not supported.
i am using command ::

v: 7za.exe xyz ac.zip for zip file "xyz ac.zip" 
v: unrar.exe abc y.rar for rar file "abc y.rar"

Answer (score 1):

You've almost answered yourself - put the filename in quotes!
Look at the end of your line:

```
7za.exe xyz ac.zip for zip file "xyz ac.zip"
```

Also the paths should be given - you have three options:
1. `cd` to the directory where `7za.exe` file is and alter the command to have full path to `"xyz ac.zip"`.
2. `cd` to the directory where `"xyz ac.zip"` file is and alter the command to have full path to `7za.exe`.
3. Add `7za.exe` folder to `system path`, `cd` to the directory where `"xyz ac.zip"` file is and execute your command unmodified.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i tried this previously it is not working. i am getting error as incorrect command line.

Comment: i am using V:\>7za.exe "V:\xyz ac.zip"

Comment: And both 7za.exe and xyz ac.zip are in the main directory of drive V? Then try 7za.exe "V:\\xyz ac.zip"

Comment: yes both are in drive V. and i checked V:\>7za.exe "V:\\xyz ac.zip" even this is giving same error

Comment: i found what is issue we need to give parameter x for 7zip then it is working fine. like V:\>7za.exe X "V:\\xyz ac.zip"  Thank you